# javascript and jsp to get the javascript variable in to my jsp page

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsp, session

I have my javascript variable ass name array in this i have to print this selected values in to my jsp page.

This is my sample code (For Example):

```
var namesArray = [];
var checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
for(var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    checkBoxes[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
     if(this.checked){
            console.log(this.value);
namesArray.push(this.value);
console.log(namesArray);
                }
    });
}
```

tell how to get this var in my jsp and also to use in session......

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the array to servlet through the query string while submitting and can get the values in servlet using  request.getParameterValues

something like

```
String names[]=  request.getParameterValues("namesArray")
```

Comment: without the submit button can i get the value from the javascript to my String names[]

Comment: if you don't want to submit the whole form..use ajax.

Comment: ya sure but i dont know much about ajax can you  refer any link for this example or if you have example post it